# UML Domain Model

Tags: java, uml, object-oriented-analysis, domain-model

I'm trying to get into Java oriented programming,
and have seen this characterisation a few times.
Specifically the `*`; I know that the `1..*` means that a Section belongs to Infinite number of articles but at least 1. but what does `*` by itself mean `0..*` ?, `1..*` ?

[image]

I know this might seem like a minor grammar thing, but I haven't come across this specific way in any text books. I'm just trying to understand what is meant by it.

Comment: *: ...i know that the 1..**  means...

Comment: A quick search will find any number of UML tutorials, e.g. https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-class-diagram-tutorial/

Comment: i know.. its more of theory vs practice. since i cant find the deffinition of * by it self in any textbooks, since it does to aper just by it self. thow irl implimentations, ive seen they just do the * by itself

Comment: Java has nothing to do with UML, except that UML is a modeling method to model class relationships. It could be used with any oo language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1 means 1 and only 1
- 1..* means >= 1
- 0..* means >= 0
- a single star means >= 0 means 0..*

Note : Some UML tools use N instead of star

Comment: you're welcome. if my answer is OK for you, you can accept it to close your question

Comment: and if you need to communicate you model with someone else you can pronounce * "many" so 1..* mean a one to many relationship.